# How do I make items in an Ionic list smaller (less tall)?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

The items in a standard `ion-list` of `ion-items` are too big for my app. How do I make them vertically smaller/shorter?

It seems that trying to modify the margin properties of the `.item` class yields results that are, well, complete nonsense. This is not the answer. Modifying the padding properties of the same seems not to do anything. Also not the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the properties of the `.item-content` class.

The following code will reduce the padding on list items from the comically large 16px default to a more manageable 12px.

```
.item-content {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    height: 70px;
}
```