# Ionic 2: make ion-list items smaller

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723254/how-do-i-make-items-in-an-ionic-list-smaller-less-tall), but it pertains to ionic 1 where the `ion-item` still has `ion-content`. In ionic-2 there is not `ionic-content`. I've tried changing the height/padding/margin of the actual `ion-item`, and the class `item-inner` and can't seem to get a uniform "skinny-ing" of the ion-items.

**Question**: How do I make the ion-items in an ion-list skinnier/smaller/not as tall in ionic 2? Ps. this is using ionic 2 beta 10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found that the main issue with this is in the app.ios.css file native to ionic that the `.item` class that gets assigned to the `ion-item` element gets a `min-height` assigned to it of 4.4 rem. I'm not sure where that value came from or why it's 4.4. So, in my .scss file pertaining to the list, I just added:

```
.item {
    min-height: 3rem; /* <- this can be whatever you need */
}
```

This made it so any changes that I made to the margins( I ended up changing the margin to 0 8px 0 0 respectively ) of the inner elements actually changed the height of the list item because they weren't bumping up against a min-height setting. See other answer for where to change the margin.

Without changing the min-height of the list item, any changes to the margins of the inner elements didn't do anything (at least for me ).

Answer (score 4):

Change the top-bottom padding on `<ion-label>`. The default is this:

```
ion-label {
  margin: 13px 8px 13px 0;
}
```

Comment: The .item-inner/.input-wrapper/ion-item still seem to be dictating the height of the the item itself even when I change to "margin: 0 8px 0 0"

Comment: Did you not see a change in height when you altered the top and bottom margin of ion-label? Or did it not affect it enough?

Comment: Neither. Check out this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/4CnShy3SsdHE1iXQW2SJ?p=preview. In the style.css you can change the top and bottom margin amounts and there is no apparent change

Comment: It appears ionic is assigning a more specific margin def for `.md ion-label`. I think the problem is that you have your `ion-label` definition in styles.css. In a normal ionic project, you should have your css at the component level in `home.scss` or global in one of the scss files in `app/theme`. That way Ionic knows to automatically use that over its defaults.

If you need to have it in styles.css, add `!important` to your margin css definition.